# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Rnd' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory

```
Public Class Form1
Dim r As New Random
Dim angka As Long = True
Dim i As Integer
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox3.Text)
    WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox3.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = "803057" + r.Next(0, 100000).ToString
    angka = Rnd(0, 100000000000000).ToDouble
    TextBox2.Text = angka
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username_member").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password_member").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub
```

End Class[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTwAX.png)

Hallo,
i have error in my project, anyone can help me ?

Comment: why are you using Rnd when you have a perfectly usable Random object (even used on the line above)

Comment: cannot random a object min 0 and max 1000000000000 ,, he said that overload, and i change Rnd to r.next like texbox1.text , and he said : 
Error BC30439 Constant expression not representable in type 'Integer'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just call method that don't exist.  There is no `Rnd` method that accepts two parameters so you can't call such a method.  If what you need is a random `Long` value then that's what you need to generate.  The way to do that would be to call `Random.NextDouble` and then perform the scaling yourself or else call `Random.NextBytes` with a `Byte` array of the appropriate size and then call `BitConverter.ToInt64`.  In this case, given that you have a specific range requirement, I'd go with the first option.

Comment: There is no example from your code.  Your code is wrong.  Do what I said.  Call `Random.NextDouble` and then scale yourself.  Have you bothered to read the documentation for that method?  Can you do simple arithmetic?  `NextDouble` gives you a valie in the range 0.0 to 1.0 and you want a value in the range 0 to 100000000000000.  Do you really need an example of multiplying two numbers?